# UITableView with custom cells

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells, which use a NSDictionary to populate their labels and images. My problem is, I have a NSArray returned from a server, with the information for each cell (NSDictionaries) inside. All of the cells are the same subclass of UITableViewCell, but I need every cell to use  a different array. Here is some code:

```
//I use this method to create the cell, and build it using the NSDictionary passed to it
+ (CategoryCell *)generateCategoryCellWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict;
{
    CategoryCell *cell;
    NSArray *xib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [xib objectAtIndex:0];

    if (dict != nil)
    {
        //build the cell
        cell.videoTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FuturaStd-CondensedBold" size:17.0f];
        cell.videoTitle.text = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(void){
            NSData *fullImageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"fullImage"]]];
            if (!fullImageData)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    [cell.contentButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:fullImageData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                });
            }
        });

        cell.numberOfViewsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views", [dict objectForKey:@"views"]];
    }
    else
    {
        //set placeholders
        cell.numberOfViewsLabel.text = @"1200 people viewed this";
        cell.numberOfLikesLabel.text = @"20 people liked this";
        [cell.contentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"video-table@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        cell.videoTitle.text = @"A Baby Dances in its Car Seat or Something";
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Here is where the cells are created

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CategoryCellIdentifier = @"categoryCell";
    CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategoryCellIdentifier];

    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [CategoryCell generateCategoryCellWithInfo:[itemsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        cell.delegate = self;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

For now, I am just using the first NSDictionary in the NSArray itemsArray, but I want to have each cell be passed a different NSDictionary within itemsArray. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you use 0 sections in your table:**

Just change `[itemsArray objectAtIndex: 0]` to `[itemsArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]` In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

**If you've got more than one `section` in your table** I would suggest to add a global variable `NSInteger indexCountForItemsArray;` and increment it each time `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

**In both cases** I would add a public method like `-(void)setInfo:(NSDictionary)dict` to the tableViewController and put in that the same/similar code like in your class method `+(CategoryCell*)generateCategoryCellWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)dict`:

```
- (void) setInfo : (NSDictionary*) dict {
    if (dict != nil) {
       //build the cell (your known code here)
    }
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView : (UITableView*) tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath : (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
    static NSString *CategoryCellIdentifier = @"categoryCell";
    CategoryCell *cell = (CategoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CategoryCellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [CategoryCell generateCategoryCellWithInfo : [itemsArray objectAtIndex: indexCountForItemsArray]];
        cell.delegate = self;
    } else {
        [cell setInfo : [itemsArray objectAtIndex: indexCountForItemsArray]];
    }

    self.indexCountForItemsArray += 1; 
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps you out.